# Create Form data driven for a class that have an array of the same class type

Tags: arrays, angular, nested-forms

I am building a form for the class Operation.

```
export class Operation { constructor(public name: string, public inputs: CustomInput[] = [],
          public outputs: CustomOutput[] = [], public wsdlPath: string ) {} }
```

It seems good but the problem that CustomInput has an attribute children which has an array of CustomInput type.

```
export class CustomInput { constructor(public name: string, public text: string, public defaultText: string,
          public complexType: boolean, public type: string, public children: CustomInput[] = [],
          public isMultiValued: boolean,
          public values: string[] = [], public indicator: string, public required: boolean,
          public isSelected: boolean, public simpleTypeVarietyOrComplexTypeContent: number,
          public choiceContent: boolean, public inputQname: string,
          public attributes: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>() ) {}
```

}

I want to build a data driven form for the operation but the problem that i couldn't create the array of the children attribute.

```
export class OperationInputLoadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
        constructor(  public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
        public selectedOperation: Operation; private operationIndex: number;
        operationRequestForm: FormGroup;
      ngOnInit() {this.initForm(); }
       private initForm() {
       let operationName: any;
        let operationInputs: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
       let operationInputsChildren: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
      if (this.selectedOperation.hasOwnProperty('inputs')) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedOperation.inputs.length; i++ ) {
          operationInputs.push(
            new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].name),
        text: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].text),
        defaultText: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].defaultText),
      complexType: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].complexType),
      type: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].type),
      isMultivalued: new 
      FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].isMultiValued),
      values: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].values),
      indicator: new 
     FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].indicator),
      required: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].required),
      isSelected: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].
       isSelected),
      simpleTypeVarietyOrComplexTypeContent: new 

  FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].
  simpleTypeVarietyOrComplexTypeContent),
      choiceContent: new 
        FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].choiceContent),
      inputQname: new 
       FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].inputQname),
        attributes: new 
        FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].attributes),
      children: new FormArray( [] );
      // here I want to loop over all its element because children has type 
         CustomInput[]
      // I have done this but seems don't work 

       /* if(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
          for(let j = 0; j < this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children.length; j ++ ) {
            operationInputsChildren.push(
              new FormGroup({
                name: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].name),
                text: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].text),
                defaultText: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].defaultText),
                complexType: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].complexType),
                type: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].type),
                isMultivalued: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].isMultiValued),
                values: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].values),
                indicator: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].indicator),
                required: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].required),
                isSelected: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].isSelected),
                simpleTypeVarietyOrComplexTypeContent: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i]
                  .children[j].simpleTypeVarietyOrComplexTypeContent),
                choiceContent: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].choiceContent),
                inputQname: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].inputQname),
                children: new FormControl(this.selectedOperation.inputs[i].children[j].children),
              })
            );
          }
    } */
      })); }}
  operationName = this.selectedOperation.name;
  this.operationRequestForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  wsdlPath: [this.wsdlPath],
  name: [operationName],
  inputs: operationInputs,
  operationDateInvoke: [],
  operationTimeInvoke: []
  });}
 onSubmit() {console.log(this.operationRequestForm.value);  
 this.wsdlOpService.planifyOperationInvokeByDate
 (this.operationRequestForm.value);}
 ngOnDestroy() {this.subscription.unsubscribe();}
 private navigateBack() {
 this.router.navigate(['../']);}
 onCancel() {this.navigateBack();}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Check this [**tutorial**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2).

Comment: I have read it. It isn't the same case. The adress class is simple. It hasen't an attribute which has Attribute type.

Comment: The operation class has an attribute inputs. This inputs attribute is an array of CustomInput object. So it has the attribute children which is an array of CustomInput. How I can create the from array of children attribute of inputs of class Operation.